# How to generate types for vue files

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I created the default project using Vue CLI 3, with Typescript and Webpack enabled. Types mostly work. I can import `.vue` components from other components fine and the types all work.

However if I import a `.vue` file from a `.ts` file the types do not work. For example Vue CLI generates `main.ts` which contains:

```
import App from "./App.vue";
```

However the type for `App` actually comes from the included `shims-vue.d.ts`

```
declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from "vue";
  export default Vue;
}
```

So Typescript thinks `App` is just an alias for `Vue`, which isn't the case. Is there any way I can fix this? I've tried adding `"declaration": true` to `tsconfig.json`, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: What do you mean with "types all work"? You are exporting `VueConstructor` inside every single file component. What do you need this for and how are you using that imported component inside a .ts file ?

Comment: Ah, I'm not - I'm using Vue class component so I'm actually exporting a class derived from Vue in each component. When I import it from other `.vue` files it correctly imports that class, so I can do something like `(someElement as MyComponent).aMethod()`. If I do that from a `.ts` file I get a type error that `aMethod()` does not exist on the type `Vue`.